# Query SQLite table for column names and type without using Pragma?

Tags: sqlite, schema

Is there a way to query a SQLite table, via sql Select, for specific schema information such as column name and type without using the pragma?

Using pragma:

```
PRAGMA table_info('TABLENAME')
```

Alternative: 
    ?

Answer (score 1):

You could query the [sqlite_master table](https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#sqlite_master) for the original CREATE TABLE statement.

And in recent SQLite versions, you can use

```
SELECT * FROM pragma_table_info('TableName');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use :-

```
SELECT sql FROM sqlite_master WHERE name = 'mytable' AND type = 'table';
```

This would return the SQL used to create the table named **mytable**.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,TASK TEXT NOT NULL,TASK_DESC TEXT NOT NULL,DATE TEXT NOT NULL)
```